# In how many ways can 9 people stand in a row for a group photograph, if 3 people are a family and need to stand together?

Tags: combinatorics

Are the three family members treated as one person so that the combination is:
$_9C_6$ or is just $_9C_3$ (three family members). Thanks for any help.

Comment: There are other ways of counting. The *leftmost* person in the family can be in positions $1$ to $7$, so $7$ choices. Then the family can be arranged in $3!$ ways, and the rest of the people can fill the empty slots in $6!$ ways, for a total of $(7)(3!)(6!)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, standing in a row means order matters, so you want a permutation not a combination. You can treat the three people as one, but then you have to remember that those three people have 3! ways to order themselves and yet stand together, so it should be 7! * 3!.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's tackle the family of $3$.  Since there are $3$ choices for the first slot, $2$ remaining choices for the second, and whoever's left is the third, then there are $3!$ ways they can stand together as a block.

Next, view the family as a single block.  The problem then becomes, "How many ways are there for $7$ people to stand next to each other?".

If you understand why there are $3!$ ways for the family to stand together, then it shouldn't be too hard to finish up from here to get your final answer.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this question into 2 bits, the permutation for the family and the permutation for the group.

For the family, there are $3!$ different combinations of how you can arrange them.

Since all family members need to stick together, so when you calculating the permutation for the group, you can think of these 3 people as 1. So the group has only 7 "people", which has $7!$ combinations.

Putting all these together, the number of combination of how you can arrange these 9 people is $3! \times 7! = 30240$